# mat-list in Angular doesn't show any name

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a component that generates a list with the name of some values in an array. Problem is: the list doesn't show anything, even if therea re like 20 values in the array.

TS:

```
export class ListaEventiComponent implements OnInit {
  results:EventoServer[] = []
  constructor(  public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ListaEventiComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data:EventoServer[] ) {
      this.results = data
      console.log(this.results)
     }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
  <mat-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let evento of results | keyvalue">
      {{evento.descrizione}}
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-list>
  </div>
```

Comment: what are you comparing using keyvalue ?

Comment: what is in results?

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple issues here.

1. Why do you need a `keyValuePipe` when the results are already an array? `KeyValuePipe` is supposed to be used when we want to iterate an object or map.
2. Since you used `keyValuePipe` angular will convert your array into key, values with key being array index and value being the value in array at that index. This is not required.
3. When using `keyValuePipe`, we need to access data as `evento.key` or `evento.value`. This could be the reason why `{{evento.descrizione}}` is undefined and nothing is shown on the screen.

So just remove the `KeyValuePipe` in the `ngFor` expression. It should work.